# SQL/PHP - Calling Same Table Twice Based on Column Value

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement

Here is a general setup of my table:

```
users
-------------
user_id | user_first | user_last | user_friendlist
1       | John       | Doe       | 2,3
2       | Jimmy      | John      | 1,3
3       | Papa       | John      | 1,2
```

1. First, I will select the above table using user_id and retrieve user_friendlist.
2. Then, I want to use user_friendlist and retrieve user_first & user_last.

I tried Left JOIN, but I am not sure how to call the same table twice... Please help! It gets all confusing when attempting to do a prepare statement.

General code for the first part:

```
$selectData = $con->prepare("SELECT 
                                    user_friendlist
                                FROM 
                                    users
                                WHERE 
                                    user_id=?");


    $selectData->bind_param("i", $user_id); 

    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];

    $selectData -> execute(); 
    $selectData-> bind_result($user_friendlist);    

    $arr = array();
    while (  $selectData -> fetch() ) {
        $arr[] = $user_friendlist;
    }

    echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: i would highly recommend you take that user_friendlist column out and create a many to many table to relate users to one another. joins are not really designed to be done on a column that contains multiple key values. not saying you cant do it, but it's ugly / not performant. the many to many table would have columns like friend_request_user_id, friend_repsonse_user_id (whatever names makes sense to you and describe the difference between the two id fields)

Comment: you should have another table name `user_friend` for example with two column `user_id` and `friend_id`

Comment: `user_id` and `friend_id` will be foreign keys for the column `users.user_id`

Comment: and you are using `mysqli` not `pdo` right ?

Comment: I was hoping to keep all user information under one roof.. I guess best to separate friendlist to another table and call using LEFT JOIN to users to retrieve first name and last name?

Comment: Yes, it is mysqli @robert

Comment: `left join` if the friend can be not exist , `join` if the friend have to be exist

Comment: Thank you! I guess a lot of new adjustments on my part ;]

Comment: do you know how to create and control foreign key ?

Comment: Honestly, no.. I don't have proper learning channel. I just browse, trial, implement. can say I have minimal knowledge on SQL... :S

Comment: then you should use foreign key to control what happens when a user delete , for example you can prevent delete user if he have friends , or delete all of his friend and friends who have him , or change the value of his id to null when he is deleted read more about it here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have two tables users and friends

users will be like

```
| user_id | user_first | user_last | 
| 1       | John       | Doe       |
| 2       | Jimmy      | John      |
| 3       | Papa       | John      |
```

and friends

```
| user_id | freind_id | 
| 1       | 2         |
| 1       | 3         |
| 2       | 1         |
| 2       | 3         |
| 3       | 1         |
| 3       | 2         |
```

`user_id` is the program key for table `users`

`user_id` and `friend_id` are the primary key for table `friend`

`friends.user_id` and `friends.friend_id` is foreign keys for `users.user_id`

the query will be like

```
SELECT users2.user_first AS friend_first,users2.user_last AS friend_last
-- ,users1.user_first AS user_first,users1.user_last AS user_last 
-- uncomment the last line to get the user info with his friends
FROM users as users1
join friends
ON users1.user_id=friends.user_id
JOIN users AS users2
ON users2.user_id=friends.friend_id
WHERE users1.user_id=1
```

the query result is

```
| friend_first | friend_last |
| Jimmy        | John        |
| Papa         | John        |
```

Comment: Sweet, thank you! I will use this instead of my original split by , and all that nasty stuff.

Comment: wait there are something wrong in this query i will fix it soon

Comment: Still setting up the DB :P Thank you for double checking

Comment: fixed and tested at first time it was selecting the user name not his friends

Comment: how to also retrieve friends.user_id along with the user_first and user_last? I think i can figure it out but wondering if you know it with a short change of the script :P

Comment: add `users2.user_id` :D